# How can I remove the resize corner from an NSPanel that is an HUD Window

Tags: objective-c, resize

I'm trying to remove the resize corner from an NSPanel HUD styles.

This is what I'm trying right now.

NSUInteger currentStyleMask = [somePanel styleMask];
[somePanel setStyleMask: currentStyleMask | !NSResizableWindowMask];

I also get a warning that NSWindow may not respond to setStyleMask and it isn't defined in NSWindow.h, however it is defined in the NSWindow documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only set the style mask of an `NSWindow` at creation time, you can't change it once the window has been instantiated.

You need to create the window programmatically and initialize it by calling `-initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` and pass in your desired style mask.

If you want to manipulate the window in Interface Builder instead of creating it programmatically, you'll need to subclass `NSWindow`, override `-initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:` and pass in your style mask to `super`'s implementation. You can then assign your subclass to the window in Interface Builder.